# Exclude properties in HandyJSON

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm using the HandyJSOn framework to serialize and deserialize objects in Swift3. Now I've the problem that I want to exclude some properties from this process. I tried to follow the steps given on the GithHub page but I can't get to work:

```
class MyClass : HandyJSON {
  private var excludeThisProperty : String

  public func mapping(mapper: HelpingMapper) {
    mapper >>> self.excludeThisProperty
  }
}
```

The compiler fials with the error:

```
binary operator >>> cannot be applied to operands of type HelpingMapper and String
```

+++ Example +++

```
class MyClass : HandyJSON {
    private let myPropertyDefault : String? = "example"
    private var myProperty : String

    public required init() {
        myProperty = myPropertyDefault!
    }

    public func reset() {
        myProperty = myPropertyDefault!
    }

    public func mapping(mapper: HelpingMapper) {
        mapper >>> self.myPropertyDefault
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your string to optional :

```
private var excludeThisProperty : String?
```

Example code :

```
let jsonString = "{\"excludeThisProperty\":\"sdfsdf\"}"

if let myclass = MyClass.deserialize(from: jsonString) {
    print(myclass)
}

class MyClass : HandyJSON {
    private var myPropertyDefault : String? = "example" // changed from let to var
    private var myProperty : String

    public required init() {
        myProperty = myPropertyDefault!
    }

    public func reset() {
        myProperty = myPropertyDefault!
    }

    public func mapping(mapper: HelpingMapper) {
        mapper >>> self.myPropertyDefault
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I was too rash: Unfortunately the problem still exists. Now the error is: "binary operator >>> cannot be applied to operands of type HelpingMapper and String?"

Comment: I posted a new example. With this one you should be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Change `myPropertyDefault` from `let` to `var`

Comment: Great it works! Thanks a lot! Because I'm always interested in background knowledge: Can you please give some keywords why I have to use var instead of let?